# Nest js passing dynamic object from controller to service without using parameter

Tags: dependency-injection, pipe, nestjs, nest, nestjs-config

I'm using nest js.I have the following scenario where i need to pass customId from controller where i got it using interceptor when i handled the http request.
I need to access customId in service without passing it in the props. Is their a way to inject custom variables ?

Answer (score 0):

Adding "customId" is request object `req.customId` should work.

Comment: I already got in my controller but i need to be able to do the following 
UserController --> UserService --> UserRepository 
I need to read it from repository without passing it to service than repository

Answer (score 0):

I created an customRepository

```
@Injectable({scope:Scope.REQUEST})
export class IdService{
  id:string='';
  public setId(id:string){
    this.id=id
  }
}
```

In the controller i inject it and use setId then i read id from userRepository

controller:

```
this.repo.setId(body.payload.tax)
```

userReposiotry:

```
   const id= this.repo.id
```

Comment: Also i added IdService in repositories in user.module.ts